# What do I do when a moderator has a "God" complex?

Tags: discussion, chat, new-users, moderators

Recently, I gave my opinion to a moderator on the Stack Exchange Movies & TV chat room and was scolded like a child. It is very frustrating to me to make a comment in the chat room and constantly be scrutinized for not being in their "club".

I read a previous question, *[What recourse do I have if I believe a moderator has abused their privileges?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28867/what-recourse-do-i-have-if-i-believe-a-moderator-has-abused-his-her-privileges)*. The answer to that question is:

> - Send a message to the Stack Exchange team via the "contact us" link at the bottom of any page with your complaint and links to the questions/answers.
> - Flag for moderator attention and request a second moderator to have a look.
>
> For the record, here are levels of moderation (from highest to lowest):
>
> - Developers - Stack Exchange developer team
> - Community team
> - Diamond moderators - Elected by the community or appointed as moderators "pro tempore" for beta-sites.
> - Regular users with reputation points-based privileges

There are only a handful of users that chat in that room, and I believe that most of them are moderators due to the fact that they have the power to delete comments/questions, etc. They all agree with the **one** moderator who is basically their "leader" So, that is where my frustration lies.

Also, there is *never* any chat about movies and TV. It is only complaining about ID questions or putting down other Stack Exchange sites if they are beta. It is just frustrating because I love movies and TV, but unfortunately, the chat room never discusses any of that. They are all too worried about the way their Stack Exchange site looks to other Stack Exchange sites… (but only the ones that matter).

What can I do as a new user to chat about Movies & TV on Stack Exchange without a moderator always in the room "judging" every word I say?

Comment: Huh? I have chatted there before and found them to be helpful and nice

Comment: @santiago it is just one person, but it is like they all seem to agree with that one person over everything, even if that person is wrong.  It is the only chat room I have been in that is like that.  I am glad that you had a positive experience, but I have not.

Comment: Can you link to the transcript? this question is a bit 'empty' without it

Comment: @santiago Moderator deleted all.

Comment: @EnergyNumbers I read that question before I posted this one.  The answer was to "flag" another moderator to oversee the other one's actions.  That unfortunately will not work in this case.  There are only a handful that chat in that room and I believe that they are all moderators since they have the power to delete comments/questions, etc.

Comment: @Brad please read the answer there a little more closely. It says more than "flag another moderator", and completely answers your question. Please do bear in mind that all comments in chat should be professional and respectful. Oh, and [this is worth a read](http://meta.stackexchange.com/help/be-nice).

Comment: @Brad honestly, without context, we're just looking at a rant here. (Wanted to explain the reason for downvotes)

Comment: For anyone not aware of the context and before taking the accusations in this question for granted, here is the respective question on [meta.movies.se] for the necessary context: http://meta.movies.stackexchange.com/q/1896/49.

Comment: Calling a mod coward for suggesting you to bring a discussion to meta and then meta rant and now this. I think you need to think before accusing a mod without any reason.

Answer (score 6):

The Contact Us email page should go towards the Community Managers email box, actual SE employees, who oversee elected/appointed mods (who are not employees). They may or may not believe there is anything to do about the issue. They can see deleted chat messages, just point them towards a time/date and/or a chat message link, and they will look around.

It takes a few days for a reply.