# Where it is possible to challenge the decision of the moderator of one of the Stack Exchange projects?

Tags: support, moderation

(English is not my native language)

Today [*I was blocked*](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/users/199934/%D0%A1%D0%B0%D1%88%D0%B0-%D0%A7%D0%B5%D1%80%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85) on Russian Stack Overflow.
Blocking justification:

> Информация на странице вашей учетной записи вводит в заблуждение относительно вашей личности. Там размещён портрет и ссылки на учетные записи в социальных сетях совершенно другого человека. Это просто по-человечески плохо, а ещё явно запрещено пользовательским соглашением.
>   Я удалил всю подобную информацию. В будущем, пожалуйста, избегайте любой возможности того, что вас примут за кого-то другого.

Translate:

> Information on the page of your account misleads concerning your personality. There the portrait and links to accounts on social networks absolutely of other person is placed. It simply is properly bad, and it is obviously forbidden by terms of service.
>  
>   I removed all similar information. In the future, please, avoid any possibility of that you will be taken for someone another.

In my profile there was a [*photo taken by me*](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/279079/326972) of my Beloved and the link to Her profile in a social network. Information was in my profile 3 months, my profile collected more than 200 viewings, anybody didn't say to me that my profile violates rules.

Well, I understand that, perhaps, photos and links to other people are forbidden. **I would remove information if it is forbidden.** But **I wasn't warned that my actions are forbidden before blocked me.**

---

[*The answer*](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2950/199934) of the moderator of Russian of Stack Overflow.

> Если конфликт еще только назревает, участник получает устное предупреждение. Далее следует бан на неделю/месяц/год за первое/второе/третье серьезное нарушение соответственно. Иногда может применяться бан менее недели.

Translate:

> If the conflict just becomes ripe, the participant receives the oral prevention. Further the ban for a week/month/year for the first/second/third serious violation respectively follows. The ban can sometimes be applied less than a week.

[*The answer*](https://ru.meta.stackoverflow.com/a/2949/199934) of that moderator which blocked me.

> При первом случае нарушений мы часто ограничиваемся предупреждением.

Translate:

> At the first case of violations we are often limited to the prevention.

---

But I wasn't warned about inadmissibility of my actions. If I was told that my actions violate the rules Russian Stack Overflow, I would remove the forbidden content from my profile. It is my first blocking, I respect and I don't want to violate the rules of the Stack Exchange projects.

The moderator blocked me without the prevention that contradicts words of moderators which I provided above in the text. Where projects Stack Exchange is the court where the contested decision moderators individual projects? Thanks.

Comment: @MonicaCellio, thanks for the link!