# Where do complaints about poor or inappropriate moderators go?

Tags: support, moderation, moderators

What is the process for reporting moderator behavior that is inappropriate or unhelpful?

I have a moderator who is:

- acting passive-agressive by being argumentative in comments as he effectively answers my question, while refusing to bother to actually answer it (we've all seen that in regular users),
- is making "suggestions" designed to provoke rather than help, and
- is being snide and confrontational.

Is there a productive way to draw attention to this without escalating too much or being confrontational?

---

Note that the question here isn't (at least not quite yet) about [abuse of power](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/28867/164163) as much as it is about being a regular old badly behaved user.

Comment: If you're looking at them as merely a user, then just flag it for moderator attention and let the mods take care of it. Most sites encourage mods to not handle flags that they're too close to, so one of the other mods should be the one to handle the flag.

Comment: So you think that advertising that a mod has "gone a bit off" on the main network page *isn't* provocative?

Comment: @Catija: Good point. Fixed!

Comment: It's probably also good to keep in mind that "I got into a disagreement with a mod" doesn't mean the mod is wrong, inappropriate, unhelpful, or any of the other things you've suggested. Mods are people, and people certainly can behave badly, but it's good to to be open to the possibility that what you see as unhelpful or provocative might actually have been a misunderstanding, on your part, theirs, or both. I'm not making any judgment about what exactly happened with you, just suggesting that you don't leap to conclusions, especially if you're currently feeling provoked.

Comment: It's also worth pointing out that, regardless of whether you see this as abuse of power or not, the answer on the linked question would be the same answer you would get were this reopened. There are only so many ways to "complain about users (mods or otherwise)"... you use "contact us" to reach a CM or you flag and ask for a second mod's opinion.

Comment: @Jefromi: Agreed. I think some of the remarks are pretty clearly intended to provoke though. And the mod clearly didn't get the question but dug in too deep with objections to back down. That's why I don't really think it's an "abuse of power". It's more like: Dude, that's not really how a mod should behave; see how that looks (at least to me)?

Comment: @Catija: Yeah. Agreed: that answer pretty much covers it for practical purposes.