# What recourse have users, if the "contact us" link to SE employees doesn't help?

Tags: support, contact

> The "contact us" link to SE employees does not result in useful contact. What I've gotten back is clearly a form letter saying "Generally, if you have a question about a site or an action taken on it, the best place to ask is on Meta", etc.
>                       – [Daniel R. Collins](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/341383/daniel-r-collins)
>                   [Apr 11 at 12:42](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28867/what-recourse-do-i-have-if-i-believe-a-moderator-has-abused-his-her-privileges#comment955652_28869)

What recourse have users if the above is true?

Comment: Recourse for what? That comment isn’t very meaningful. I’m sure the contact form results in useful contact a lot, it’s just not the best place to ask general questions that could be answered on Meta.

Comment: For the four or fives times I have used that option all responses where helpful to me.

Answer (score 11):

None, really. The buck *kinda* stops there.

While in *theory* in some cases you can ask on meta - meta's a place for clarification (as opposed to rants), and at a certain level SE's policies, and by extension how SE's employees handle your query can override meta consensus. If you need to ask, it hasn't actually happened.

Staff interventions are *rare*, of course. Most sites don't have *much* intervention and its usually gentle, but at some point, if you *really* are unhappy about the mods *and* the people who run the sites, you either need to adjust your expectations, or find a place you're happier in.

By the time you've reached the point of a "contact us" message, you've already gone through a good chunk of the folks who run the site looking at your query. You can't really expect a different reaction at this point.

In my experience, usually *someone* reaches out to me when there's a contact us message related to my actions, and I've had a chance to explain what happened. There's not always a need for action in many cases (and I don't need to be aware of SE's response. I just need to know whether my actions in that instances were appropriate).

Chances are as such, someone's reviewed and passed on your message to the appropriate person.