# Is flagging too many posts to add the citation banner grounds for suspension?

Tags: discussion, flags, moderator-tools, low-quality-posts, account-suspension

This question arises from my personal experience -

Suppose I have a per day flag limit of 90 flags, and I have been incessantly working hard on hunting out bad content across the main site to flag low quality and "un-sourced" answers.

However, after a certain number of days, the mods on the site contact me via chat and in an impersonal ("assertive/ admonishing") tone proclaim "*since it's very tedious for us to add citations manually, please don't flag to add the citation banner more than 7 to 8 times per day*".

I don't flag for the next day, however, me being a voracious reader, I start reading through answers and find lots of low quality, unsalvageable material and am thus driven to flag it. Without realizing, the flag count might have crossed the mod prescribed "7-8 flags per day" limit.

The mod again admonishes me in chat.

In the coming days, due to some "apparently rude behaviour" arising in response to some "misogynistic views" by some of fellow users of the site, a comment ruckus ensues, which leads to my suspension.

In the suspension message it says:

> "flagging for more than prescribed by the Moderator is also cited as a warning ground".

#### Questions:

- Are site mods within their "legal right" to prescribe a certain flag limit per user according to their own whims? If yes, then why does the system give users so many flags per day, if mods are free to prescribe a limit on general users?
- I get that being a moderator is a tough task, but that's a given when one undertakes that role, therefore– Isn't responding to a perfectly reasonable flag (regardless of the quantity - even if 100 flags) a duty of moderators, and general users are thus perfectly within their right to flag as much "low quality content" as allowed in a day by the system?
- Can not adhering to the "prescribed flag limit" directive by the moderator serve as a valid and fathomable ground for getting a suspension?

Comment: To me this, and your comments on @Glorfindel 's answer, reads like you have a grudge with a certain moderator. In that case have a look at: https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/28867/what-recourse-do-i-have-if-i-believe-a-moderator-has-abused-their-privileges

Comment: "In the MOD - message it says:" Usually meaningful moderator messages are longer than a sentence. It would help us, if you could share more of the private message, in order to help you, or do let us know if it is just that one sentence.

Comment: If you get a warning, whether you know it or not, you can heed the warning; or ignore it and see what happens. The meta of the site in question is where you should have discussed this first, before coming here; only if there was no resolution there should you have appealed here.

Comment: @Rob, they're suspended on the site, so they couldn't have appealed on the site meta.

Comment: @BhargavRao that's usually not an acceptable excuse to just (ab)use meta.se then

Comment: @BhargavRao, yes, it's common that people don't correctly read what is written. They, like you, simply ignored what was written and interpreted in favor of you being correct.

Comment: @Tinkeringbell I think this question is fine here. Whilst the example is fairly narrow and linked to one single event. The actual question(s) posed are more broadly applicable.

Comment: @Rob, I don't get it. Can you clarify what I ignored and I what I misinterpreted? My apologies if I mentioned something wrong.

Comment: @Luuklag That's not the argument Bhargav set out to make, they only mentioned an inability to post on site specific meta as justification for keeping this post here. Like I said, that specific argument is *usually* not an acceptable excuse, it circumvents restrictions. If there are any other arguments for keeping the post, fine.

Comment: @Tinkeringbell, Uhm, I didn't justify keeping the post here, I mentioned that they were suspended there which is why they couldn't have posted there.

Comment: Okay, If it's thought out already, that I might be abusing the META Privilege, then the only recourse I have is deleting this post first and then my account. Thanks for your help everyone.

Comment: @Palpatine I'm sorry you feel that way. People raised a legitemate concern, which was properly refuted in the other comments. Perhaps you should take some time to calm your mind before you make rush decisions.

Comment: an off-note: there is a legal term called "abuse of rights" (see [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Abuse_of_rights) for a brief intro). If mods asked you to tone down your flags because you create too much work for them, you should've followed the advice and tone it down. And yes, mods are in their right to issue a suspension as a punitive measure - since you were warned *more than once* as it seems, the ground for suspension is quite solid.

Answer (score 14):

*Any* problematic behaviour can, when repeated, lead to a suspension. It's not just limited to the ones explicitly listed in [A Day in the Penalty Box](https://stackoverflow.blog/2009/04/06/a-day-in-the-penalty-box/).

> If we think you are reachable, and the behavior is one that we feel can change, we will try to warn you via email first when there are behavior problems — so that we can address them before they become deeper problems. But I make no guarantees; the community moderators are very, very busy and there are a lot of things that need their attention. The odds of moderators contacting you with a warning first will be in direct proportion to how much evidence you’ve given us that you are, in fact, a potentially valuable and contributing member of the community.
>
> Depending on the severity of the problem behavior — and at the complete discretion of the moderator — your account will be placed in **timed suspension** for anywhere from 1 to 365 days.

The blog post is from 2009 and ♦ moderators have more ways to reach problematic users than email (though I would personally prefer to send a moderator message instead).

Have you thought of other solutions to improve the answers? E.g. by looking up the citations yourself, or adding comments to ask the authors to provide them?

> why give users so many flags/per day then

Because not 1) all flags reach the moderator queue, e.g. flags for closure 2) that limit is based on high-volume sites like Stack Overflow. You can hardly moderate effectively on Stack Overflow with only 20 flags per day.

Flagging is important, but some flags are more important than others. I've just been appointed here on Meta Stack Exchange and one of the differences with my other sites is that there are quite a few flags pending for staff, and it's not easy to see whether there is anything urgent to do for me. So I can understand how the moderators on your site might feel about your flags.

Comment: They're not destroying you, a site suspension is always temporary.