# Is there an external space dedicated or strongly related to Stack Exchange Community?

Tags: discussion, community

The [chat](/questions/tagged/chat) initially referred to as "the third place", [Web-based IRC for the Trilogy?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/48249/289691), for whatever reason, has been left at the bottom of the [feature-request](/questions/tagged/feature-request) queue. I'm wondering if there is already another place where the core community of Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange is gathering together, or if it doesn't already exist, what could be a good platform for this audience?

I know something in Discord (not sure if it's a server, a channel or what) was promoted as a reaction to unfortunate events related to Monica's separation as a community moderator (Update: I added section to add some sample links to posts mentioning Discords "something"). It is being promoted again, but it looks to me that it is pointed to people that already made up their minds about certain actions to take in the short term.

I would like to know if there is a "neutral" space with complementary features to what we already have here, free of "conflict of interest" but also with a good behavior policy where posts did not get "drowned with downvotes". I know there should be some way to moderate the participation. Learning something new compatible with SO / SE mind-alike minds will be nice.

### Posts in Meta Stack Exchange having links to external spaces

- [Mithical's Answer](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/378935/289691) to [Is it ok for a moderator to join a private WhatsApp or Telegram group with users from the same site they moderate?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/378934/289691) including a link to a Discord server.

#### Related

- [Should SE move in the long term to SLACK / DISCORD or chat alike system?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/330917/289691)

##### Background

- [Meta Meta Stack Overflow?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/54973/289691)
- [Give each site a parallel site for polling, recommendations and subjective-ish stuff](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/57383/289691)

Comment: There is a discord server: https://discord.gg/abJWUdTF

Comment: @mousetail Thank you. I'm not familiar with Discord. I understand that there might be multiple invitation links. The one in Mithical's answer (link added to the question) is https://discord.gg/PbEPURd . Is any difference between using one invitation link or another?

Comment: There's also a half-dead subreddit where mostly people go to rant about their bad experiences: https://www.reddit.com/r/stackexchange/

Comment: @Rubén There can be many invite links to a server, any member can create more invite links

Comment: I think discord is the best option as there are the most people listening / interacting. There may even be places on that discord where you could have some kind of neutral discussion.

Comment: Discord is borderline spyware however. Scanning your computer, keeping track of what programs you have installed and sending information about it... somewhere.

Comment: Charcoal has some presence in https://keybase.io/ though it's probably too obscure to be viable for the larger community.

Comment: "if there is already another place where the core community of Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange is gathering together" - Do you mean for content creation? Then codidact is an alternative. For hanging out? Meta is still the only place I go for meta information about SO/SE.

Comment: @Trilarion I mean for chat, discussion, polling and collaboration about Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange community's common / general interest topics like network-wide available features and norms (code of conduct, mod-agreement-policy, and alike).

Comment: There is also an official Discord server for SO collectives: https://discord.com/invite/u8HwGkUE3H (see [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/collectives/r-language/bulletins/76168959/join-the-discord-server))

Comment: @smitop Based on the linked post, it appears that the Discord server is focused on the R Collective. While this information is helpful, the question is seeking recommendations for spaces with a more general scope, preferably encompassing topics of interest to all SO & SE communities.

Comment: Way back, wasn't there something with [GEOCHET](https://meta.stackexchange.com/users/5640/geochet) using an external site (that Atwood noticed here)?

Answer (score 7):

## List of alternate spaces

Below is a list of alternate spaces open to Stack Overflow, the public question and answer "website" and Stack Exchange community members to chat, discuss, and collaborate about Stack Overflow and Stack Exchange communities. Specialized and "obscure" sites are not included.

| Platform | Specific Space | Space Blurb | Remarks |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| Codidact | N/A |  | This platform is a direct "competitor" of Stack Exchange Network. Created after Stack Exchange Community 2019 "schism"[^1]. |
| Discord | [Meta discussion](https://discord.gg/PbEPURd) | Casual chat about Stack Exchange stuff | One welcome message kindly requests that users refrain from copying any content from the server to other locations without obtaining permission from the original author<sup>[ref.](https://discord.com/channels/628507458452586497/628509392987226122/634421706320248852)</sup>. They encourage new members to use the same user name used in StackOverflow (sic)<sup>[ref.](https://discord.com/channels/628507458452586497/628509392987226122/628514259214794753)</sup>. |
| Reddit | [Stack Exchange - Free, Community-Powered Q&A](https://reddit.com/r/stackexchange) |  | Created in 2011. |

[^1] "Stack Exchange Community 2019 'schism'" refers to the Stack Exchange Community affair referred in [Stack Exchange | Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Stack_Exchange) as follows (links not included):

> On September 27, 2019, a moderator of multiple Stack Exchange sites was dismissed from her moderator position, allegedly connected to behavior associated with upcoming changes to the Code of Conduct (CoC) relating to gender pronouns.[30][31][32] Many other moderators resigned or suspended their moderator activity in response to the dismissal. The company responded with two very-poorly-received messages which have since been deleted,[33] and by a slightly less negatively-received apology several days later.[34] In December 2019, the company posted a message, stating that they and the moderator had come to an agreement and expressing regret for any damage to her reputation.[35][36] Nevertheless, this, plus the sudden departure of multiple community managers (Stack Exchange employees who interact with the community), led to an erosion of trust between the community and the company — convincing many of the site's most prolific users, including many community-elected moderators and a community manager, to depart within the next few months.[37][38][39]

...

> [30]: "Firing Mods and Forced Relicensing: Is Stack Exchange Still Interested in Cooperating with the Community?". Meta Stack Exchange. September 29, 2019. Retrieved October 28, 2019.
> [31]: "Stack Overflow Inc., sinat chinam, and the goat for Azazel". Mi Yodeya Meta Stack Exchange. September 29, 2019. Retrieved October 28, 2019.
> [32]: "The Mod Firing Squad: Stack Exchange Embroiled in 'He Said, She Said, They Said' Row". The Register. October 1, 2019.
> [33]: "An Update to our Community and an Apology". Archived from the original on October 6, 2019. Retrieved October 19, 2019.
> [34]: "An apology to our community, and next steps". Archived from the original on October 19, 2019. Retrieved October 19, 2019.
> [35]: Update: an agreement with Monica Cellio Archived November 25, 2022, at the Wayback Machine. Meta Stack Exchange. Retrieved 2020-01-03.
> [36]: at 22:16, Thomas Claburn in San Francisco Jan 2, 2020. "Stack Overflow makes peace with ousted moderator, wants to start New Year with 2020 vision on codes of conduct". TheRegister.co.uk. Retrieved January 22, 2020.
> [37]: "Firing Community Managers: Stack Exchange is not interested in cooperating with the community, is it?". Meta Stack Exchange. Retrieved January 22, 2020.
> [38]: "Firing mods and forced relicensing: is Stack Exchange still interested in cooperating with the community?". Meta Stack Exchange. Retrieved January 22, 2020.
> [39]: "Why I left Stack Overflow". jlericson.com. January 17, 2020. Retrieved January 22, 2020.

## Related

- Community Building

  - It's a Stack Exchange community with many questions about Stack Exchange communities and questions related to the relationship between the community administrators, moderators and community members.

## Resources

- [Schism | Wikipedia](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schism)

Comment: I could not find a "Community Building" community in Codidact similar to "Community Building" in Stack Exchange. Is such a community already exists?

Comment: Do you mean their "site proposals" feature? https://meta.codidact.com/categories/10

Comment: @Trilarion No, I mean a Codidact's community similar to https://communitybuilding.stackexchange.com : "Q&A for community managers, administrators, and moderators."

Comment: @Rubén-PeopleFirst the Discord link appears to be dead, why not the same link as in the open letter?

Comment: i have update it @ShadowWizardStrikesBack

Comment: @ShadowWizardStrikesBack I'm sorry, I grabbed the URL from the address bar... the fix done by Arcanis looks good.

Comment: I had a quick look at the subreddit. It appears to be more or less a ghost town - less than 20 posts in the last *year*, with most of those attracting no replies - and what little is there, appears to be either blatantly off topic (e.g. looking for tech support with a smart phone, not even related to web browsing never mind any Stack Exchange site), a useless rant, or a question that could have just as easily been asked on one of our meta sites and which would be quickly closed as a duplicate there.

Comment: And then there's ... [whatever the heck this is supposed to be](https://www.reddit.com/r/stackexchange/comments/nvu9k1/wut_shchiekcemn/).