# How accurately could one differentiate between simple copy & paste of AI generated content and improved and fact checked AI generated content?

Tags: discussion, moderation, chatgpt

This question is concerned with finding possible middle grounds in the ongoing debate about banning and detecting AI generated content, so it will probably get criticized from all sides. I'm prepared.

Nevertheless I ask myself if it would be possible at the same time to:

- ban (identify and remove) AI generated content that is taken from somewhere as-is without any fact check nor any improvement whatsoever and
- keep content that among others draws on AI generated content, fact checks it and improves all the things that can be improved, potentially adding own ideas and
- has a reasonable low error rate of differentiation between the two ?

I think this is very difficult, because people who just copy&pasting AI generated content can always just claim that they did the fact checking without really doing it. While some people would certainly fact check AI content there are even more lazy people out there, so it's not like one can expect that only one of the two things will happen at any time.

It would be desirable because we decided that simply copy&pasting content from AI [is banned](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421831/temporary-policy-chatgpt-is-banned) because the quality is too low, but in many comments we nevertheless agreed that fact-checked and polished/drawn upon AI generated content is not a problem. A reliable differentiation of the two would therefore be helpful.

On the other hand, the company recently made a u-turn on banning AI content, questioning the accuracy of AI generated content detection at all (leading to a moderator strike). If we were not able to reliably detect AI generated content usage at all, there is also no hope to differentiate between the two usages. And even if we could, the second group, which is AI generated but human fact checked and edited content, is likely somewhere in between AI generated and Human generated content from their characteristics, so one would expect it to be even harder to detect or differentiate between.

So maybe this cannot be achieved and there is no middle ground and you either have to ban all AI generated content or none (meaning the strike will end by one side giving up). Or it's actually somehow possible and that's the reason for this question.

I think that the largest differences are:

- Human checked and edited AI generated content will contain a working solution while AI generated content alone will typically not be working (otherwise it would be high quality and much less controversial)
- Human checked and edited AI generated content might be more precise and to the point than AI generated content (because humans can trim the content more efficiently)

If we would have to fact check ourselves each time to be sure that the answer was already fact checked, this solution would be too inefficient (and typically not doable by moderators on for example Stack Overflow). However, maybe we could require that people actually describe how they made sure that their answer is actually working. Is this even possible? Can one credibly prove that the own answer is actually more than copy&pasted from some obscure source on the internet?

Maybe the personal history can be taken into account (somebody with a long track record of well received answers might be more likely to no just copy&past) to get more confidence. Or the time between posting answers or the number of saved drafts maybe (even though they might not be reliable)?

I think this question is interesting even in a broader context because not only copy&pasted AI generated answers are low quality. It might improve the quality of all generated answers if we had a way to be more sure of how much they were fact checked before posting.

For the sake of this question I would exclude issues with attribution and rather assume that always all sources are properly attributed. This question is just about the content.

I searched within [Is there a list of ChatGPT or other AI-related discussions and policies for our sites?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/384922/is-there-a-list-of-chatgpt-or-other-ai-related-discussions-and-policies-for-our) for similar discussions. The closest is still [How can we determine whether an answer used ChatGPT?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/421880/how-can-we-determine-whether-an-answer-used-chatgpt), [ChatGPT assisted questions](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/424983/chatgpt-assisted-questions), [Is re-worded ChatGPT answer allowed?](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/424968/is-re-worded-chatgpt-answer-allowed), which touch upon the broader subject of detectability.

Comment: This whole idea requires so much safeguards, that it's doubtful that there are any real upsides for allowing GPT answers. My position: users who can verify correctness of answer don't need GPT, people who couldn't - shouldn't answer that question in the first place. My position in full is in an answer to this [very similar question](https://meta.stackexchange.com/a/390181/1372392).

Comment: How do you differentiate an original answer from a plagiarized answer? Or an answer that is original but incorrect? Or an answer that was correct at one point but is now outdated? The problem isn't distinguishing good quality AI posts from not-good quality AI posts; The problem is that it is difficult to effectively curate content under the current system when the volume of posts gets too large. Using AI to improve or help write a post is not inherently a problem and I could do it in a way nearly impossible to detect.

Comment: @markalex "who can verify correctness of answer don't need GPT" Really? I can verify correctness and I have used GPT and will continue to use it and I'm sure I'm not the only one. And needing something may be not a good idea to think about. I don't need a lot of things but still I use them nevertheless.

Comment: @ColleenV "that was correct at one point but is now outdated" This question is only concerned with answers that are correct at the time of posting. People cannot look into the future. "Using AI to improve or help write a post is not inherently a problem and I could do it in a way nearly impossible to detect." Okay, then could you maybe write in an answer how you do that so that it is nearly impossible to detect? Then everyone should do the same but I don't believe it yet.

Comment: You've missed my point entirely. The current system doesn't scale. Stack Overflow content is full of bad posts. Questions that should be closed but aren't. Plagiarized answers. Incorrect answers. Outdated answers. If SO can't solve that problem, it can't solve the problem of bad quality AI posts either. The only reason anyone is talking about AI generated posts is because the popularity of it has caused the system that was held together with volunteer manual labor and optimism to finally be overwhelmed.

Comment: @NoDataDumpNoContribution, yes, really: you don't need chatGPT to generate answers on topics where you are a subject-matter expert. You might want too, it might save you some time, or generate some ornate phrases, but you can provide an answer without it. And I believe should.

Comment: @ColleenV Sorry. I didn't realize that you see the big picture here. I don't want to save SO, not with a single question anyway. So I have to limit myself. And I'm not even concerned about low quality AI posts. This question is more about high quality AI assisted posts.  Because you said, you can make them look like they weren't written by an AI, this would already be sufficient. Maybe we could even try that. I take a question in a tag I know a lot, find question/GPT answer pair that is correct, rewrite it and then compare detector scores before and after the rewrite.

Comment: @markalex Okay. But many other people expressed their desire to use GPT assistance in answering and others re-assured them that this is perfectly okay as long as they checked the content themselves extensively before posting. I could find and link some of  these comments, if you like. You seem to disagree with them.

Comment: @NoDataDumpNoContribution, yes I disagree with them. And to be fair, I have yet to meet reassurance that this is perfectly okay.

Comment: @NoDataDumpNoContribution I don't understand. An AI-assisted post doesn't look like it was written by AI because it wasn't; it was written by a human with AI help. If you don't want a post to be detected by a human as AI-generated, don't copy and paste AI generated text. There are no reliable automated ways to detect AI generated text.

Comment: The trouble with AI is it's still as dumb as a rock. I just asked Firefly for "an old black & white photograph of three Victorian gentlemen and a large-toothed fish they caught in a foggy swamp." I'm not sure it quite got the idea - https://i.stack.imgur.com/POJKF.jpg The difficulty is differentiating dumb users from dumb AI [LLM]. AI never checks its work. Humans are expected to, but if they write the 'english' bits out themselves then it becomes difficult, because unless you fully test it yourself, you can't see the big fish with teeth. It's still dead easy to spot the copy/pasters, though.

Comment: _"in many comments we nevertheless agreed..."_. Which comments? Who is "we"? _"also no hope to differentiate between the two usage"_ -- it's quite easy to differentiate between the two in my experience. Give it a try. _"It might improve the quality of all generated answers if we had a way to be more sure of how much they were fact checked before posting."_ -- We do have a way to fact check: human subject matter experts, upvotes/downvotes and comments. These have been working pretty well for us so far.

Comment: @ggorlen "it's quite easy to differentiate between the two in my experience." How do you differentiate between the two? If it's easy, the experience should be possible to share.

Comment: @ColleenV "An AI-assisted post doesn't look like it was written by AI because it wasn't; it was written by a human with AI help." I see. For you it's a binary thing. A text is either written by a human or an AI, even if a human was inspired by an AI it's still human and both are completely distinct. I think of it rather as a continuum, there are purely human written texts, purely AI written texts, and texts that are collaborative between humans and AI and therefore everything in between exists too. To me there are more grey levels to you more black and white. Just different ways to look at it.

Comment: @ggorlen "Which comments? Who is "we"? " I will print and reference them tomorrow. They definitely exist. We means the community. Again and again I've seen comments that using GPT as inspiration and doing fact checking isn't a problem. Haven't you seen them too? We can discuss that too, but it would be a different question. This question explores these two usages of AI content.

Comment: The community has not "agreed that fact-checked and polished/drawn upon AI generated content is not a problem". Even if you find these comments from a few people who share your view, there's no community consensus on that. If anything, the opposite is true. _We_ should not be used to refer to the community to support _your_ views, especially without citation.

Comment: @NoDataDumpNoContribution Detecting GPT is easy: brand new accounts spamming 25 answers in the span of an hour in totally random tags all of which have perfect grammar, at least half of which are flat out wrong, many that don't even address the question being asked and are poorly-formatted, and all of which sound _exactly_ like ChatGPT. "It looks like you're trying to do X". This pattern _never_ happened before LLMs came out, now it happens constantly. Poster can't even tell you much of anything about the answer when you ask for clarification, because they're just trying to farm rep

Comment: I keep hearing virtually the same proposal talking about the value add of LLMs on Stack Overflow, but I've seen zero evidence of a positive contribution it's made. Even if it happened to answer something correctly, why not just go to the LLM and ask it directly? There's no point in turning SO into a dumping ground of stale LLM answers. Not being able to post LLM answers on SO doesn't stop you from using LLMs in any way, but posting LLM answers on SO makes it much harder to get human help, which is more necessary than ever.

Comment: @ggorlen See some examples of my experience https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/387575/examples-of-chatgpt-being-right-and-wrong-on-stack-exchange/390348#390348. I could contribute hundreds of correct answers being assisted by ChatGPT4 in my field of study, but haven't done so quite simply because it currently is not allowed...

Comment: There was a post about [using AI to fix grammar](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/424036), where this usage was considered acceptable.  This is precedent that human-AI coauthored posts are acceptable to some extent.  (I'm fairly sure, going forward, I'm going to at least ask ChatGPT for feedback on my posts---something like AI peer review.)

Comment: @TomWenseleers Please re-read my post above. "Even if it happened to answer something correctly, why not just go to the LLM and ask it directly?" Is it because LLMs are so often wrong that getting a correct answer is luck? I'm talking about _net impact_ here, which is clearly negative. Getting the right answer by chance 30% of the time on a good day doesn't cut it for me (and even if it did, just ask the LLM directly...). Anyone can cherry pick a good LLM answer, but that doesn't overcome the impact of thousands of garbage answers flooding the site and overwhelming the signal to noise ratio.

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones [Using AI to help people ask questions was a disaster on SO](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/425162/we-are-seeking-functional-feedback-for-the-formatting-assistant)

Comment: @ggorlen I presume your are talking about ChatGPT3. Have you tried the paid version ChatGPT4? If I try that on 20 random SO questions (in my field so I can judge output) I get a good answer in >75% of all cases. Selective posting of the best answers & some manual editing plus good prompting (eg chain of thought) would improve this further. If it's a bad answer it's easy to tell. Have you looked at % of human written answers on SO that are any good? That's less than 1/3d I would say...

Comment: @ggorlen The accuracy of ChatGPT4 vs typical SO answers should be properly benchmarked. This https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/384410/how-often-does-chatgpt-give-an-incorrect-answer-to-an-se-question/384411#384411 at least won't cut it. Just give it 100 SO questions, get answers from ChatGPT4 & SO & have experts rate them blind. Easy enough! Your cherry picked bad presumed GPT answers also won't quite cut it...

Comment: @RebeccaJ.Stones I always thought this was acceptable usage & that ban was only against straight copy & paste GPT answers. But now they want to make it seem like even reproducing one single line of GPT code in an answer would be illegal. Ridiculous, given that GPT powered BING is now the default search engine for many... Problem also is that those moderators delete perfectly accurate answers, like mine, without the slightest subject matter knowledge... Pure insanity... A total waste of human effort...

Comment: @ggorlen If I paste in the 8 questions of mine on Cross Validated / Stats Stackexchange that were never answered into ChatGPT4 I would rate 6 out of 8 ChatGPT answers as solving my problem & being correct. That's a pretty good success rate I would say. Better than SO itself, where I didn't check any of the answers as correct because they were either beating about the bush, not solving my problem or just wrong... Plus: if I would use ChatGPT to answer any questions I would not just copy & paste - I would add a few references & reproducible, tested code e.g. That would increase quality further.

Comment: @TomWenseleers 75% accuracy is still horrible, and I haven't seen that on the site. I've flagged hundreds of GPT answers and almost all of them are wrong to some extent or another. It's mostly been used by tone deaf rep farmers who don't even understand the questions they're answering. Anyway, let's assume 100% accuracy. There's still no point in flooding SO (from which LLMs are trained) with the answers. Just ask LLMs directly to get those answers! At least with human answers, they're moderatable because they aren't posted by the dozens per hour. If you want LLMs, you can use them directly.

Comment: @ggorlen I was not talking about straight copy and paste practices. Action could still be taken against users that abuse system with straight copy & paste & which are unwilling to edit & improve posts, reply to comments or post large nrs of poorly rated answers. That could be done in fully automated way, no moderators needed there. If the OP could delete bad answers that would also prevent spam. ChatGPT4 knows a lot more than what can be found on SO. Also all of github+academic literature. Having a publicly available vetted GPT answer would still be good: would take out some of the randomness.

Comment: @TomWenseleers "...publicly available vetted GPT answer would still be good..." sounds fine to me. Let's do that on a new, different site and keep SO purely human following the system that has worked for the past 15 years building the best human-powered knowledge Q&A instead of flooding that beautiful training data with unverified LLM spew.

Comment: @ggorlen That would be possible too - that if SO would not be open to this that some other site would stand up to step in it's place. But what I fear is that traffic to SO would just collapse further, to such low levels that answers would hardly ever get answered. But a simple checkbox "GPT assisted" would also be easy enough. And you could hide those answers for the users that wouldn't want to see those if they really hate GPT... But why not take advantage of the input of all those paying ChatGPT4 users & have them contribute knowledge for free?

Comment: @TomWenseleers Going forward, the hard problem is how to _stop_ LLMs from polluting  resources, not the opposite. The _killer feature_ going forward is a resource that is guaranteed human. You don't need to encourage LLM usage--you won that battle. LLMs are here forever--you have all the access you want! We're fighting for _one space_ that doesn't have LLMs. At the very least, you should want this to [avoid degrading your training data](https://www.google.com/url?q=https://arxiv.org/abs/2305.17493&sa=U&ved=2ahUKEwjzyOLJvc3_AhWaIkQIHVcVCakQFnoECAoQAg&usg=AOvVaw3KbkLnEZP1F3ZRM12NGurW).

Comment: @ggorlen Sorry, but that's a bit of a silly stance. AI will tilt our knowledge & capabilities & education to a new level. As a result of humans & AI working together. Not against each other... Causing humans to make new discoveries & allow them to solve problems they could not solve before or alone. Your stance is like saying that mathematicians & physicists should have kept working only with pencil and paper & not have started using computers...

Comment: @TomWenseleers Not at all, I'm suggesting use computers _and_ pencil and paper where appropriate, instead of throwing away all pencil and paper and rewriting the pre-computer math and science knowledge just because computers arrived. Turning SO into another LLM dumping ground sacrifices and buries all the pre-LLM knowledge used to make LLMs in the first place. There should be separate places for both to maximize overall knowledge access and trust the origin.

Comment: @ggorlen Yes, but that's working together. Which is exactly what I propose when it comes to AI. Keep on thinking for yourself by all means. But just use it as an enabler to lift it to a new level.

Comment: @TomWenseleers When you throw away and pollute prior knowledge, that's a disabler of knowledge, not lifting anything to a new level. A world where all you can find is probablistic LLM spew trained on other probablistic LLM spew is not a good place to be.

Comment: @ggorlen After all my discussions over the last few days I also still haven't the slightest clue now how I should deal with answers that were partially inspired by GPT, but mostly self written. Are they illegal? Or allowed if I don't tell anyone GPT contributed? After all the ones that were Googling with BING also won't say they implicitly used GPT. Many say only copy & paste is forbidden. But nobody seems to know for sure. It seems that the responsible AI users like myself now should just keep quiet about their use of ChatGPT to avoid getting good answers deleted. Hardly an ideal situation.

Comment: @ggorlen On that last point - there you are assuming that our knowledge & progress would now just get stuck or something. Obviously that's not the case because we selectively copy the best working solutions & will often invent new techniques, frequently aided by AI. I already discovered several new statistical methods whilst being assisted by ChatGPT. With it saying something along the lines of "that would also be a valid technique, even if no one is doing it like that right now yet".

Comment: @TomWenseleers There's no getting stuck--nobody is telling you not to use LLMs, just don't pollute the training data and drown out the human input factor that got us this far. We're having the same discussion in two threads and I'm mostly repeating my points. Thanks for humoring me--we'll have to agree to disagree. Like I said in the other thread--you won. LLM answers will flood SO with the support of the company. I don't see them going back to the LLM ban, because it hurts their bottom line of maximizing "engagement". Please enjoy your victory and I'll see how wrong I am as time goes on.

Answer (score 3):

This was in fact being accurately achieved prior to the policy change. The change was a panicked reaction and in error.

Comment: Is this an answer? I ask for how in order to get to know details. You don't say anything about how that might have been accomplished before.

Comment: There is no objective list of criteria that can be used to directly identify AI content, it's something you do through reading and understanding what generated content looks like and more importantly, *what it does not*. it is not a mathematical formula or set of phrases that we can just regex for. Being unable to code a solution to detect it accurately doesn't mean our existing methods, aka using our brains, is ineffective at identifying these differences.

Comment: No it doesn't mean that, although typically people try to find explanations even approximate ones because there must be some, we do not simply throw dices. In this case I think it's even more difficult because the amount of AI as influence can be variable. A mixture of AI and human content should be even more difficult to detect. But nevertheless you say that it is possible with high confidence by human learning, right? Maybe you have a theory how that worked? How did people find out the difference between fully AI generated and only AI assisted content?

Comment: I don't think we've thus far tried to differentiate between the two, given our policy was a blanket ban on AI, not excluding AI assisted content. AI assisted content varies, as AI-assisted code would be much harder to differentiate from just *wrong* or *correct* code. AI "assisted" text on the other hand would be no more difficult to detect than what we've been detecting.

Comment: After all, AI assisted text is really just AI text. If you take an AI text response and modify it to look human, it's no longer AI assisted text. AI gave you an idea, and you formulated that idea in your own words.

Comment: "I don't think we've thus far tried to differentiate between the two" this probably means that the answer should rather be that we don't know because we never tried it before. "AI gave you an idea, and you formulated that idea in your own words. " But the idea is still the same? Is it only about the used words then? I thought these language models are especially good in emulating the words of humans. I thought the weakness of AI is that it cannot fact check, much less that it cannot emulate human speech well enough.

Comment: *"I thought these language models are especially good in emulating the words of humans."* that's certainly the claim, but in practice... not so much. It's great at being unpredictable, however that unpredictable nature leads to being identifiable if left unmodified. If you instead take an idea or solution presented to you by ai and provide it as an answer in your own words, that's no more detectable than someone doing the same from docs. It can certainly be problematic, in that it might still be presenting false information, but that's not what the majority of problematic cases are doing.

Comment: The goal of the old policy was to deal with the worst of the worst. If someone takes an idea presented to them by AI and presents it in their own words, that's not something that's going to be detected as easily as someone tabbing through a half dozen questions and copy/pasting an answer. That doesn't mean we shouldn't still take action against the users that are just tabbing through a half dozen questions and copy pasting an answer.

Answer (score -1):

For **programming related questions** I would say it is very **easy** to detect if ChatGPT has been used responsibly & the answer is not just a quick copy and paste:

### (1) it should feature **reproducible code** with **output or benchmark**

Since ChatGPT can't yet run code, that would be a simple and easy check to verify that the poster checked the code ran correctly & verified the answer.

and it should

### (2) feature **links** to **trustworthy sources**

E.g. Google Scholar articles etc, which would also signal that the user took some effort to do some extra verification, as ChatGPT doesn't do that by default (unless the ScholarAI or the web browsing plugin is used, but that doesn't always work so well).

Simple checks like this would ensure the accuracy of programming-related answers partially based on ChatGPT4 or GPT based Github Copilot code or the GPT based Bing search engine (which many now have as default). This is also the narrow conditions under which I would allow some usage of generative AI on SO.

See also my answer [here](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/387575/examples-of-chatgpt-being-right-and-wrong-on-stack-exchange/390348#390348), where I shared some experiences on the use of ChatGPT4 for answering Stack Overflow questions & the responses I received (including ones [for which I never received a good answer on SO, not even after 5 years, despite the question being highly ranked](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48119360/performant-2d-sdl-or-opengl-graphics-in-r-for-fast-display-of-raster-image-using/76472961?noredirect=1#comment134865427_76472961)).

It would seem unavoidable that at some stage SO will have to transition to allow [responsible use of AI](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/questions/425211/current-position-on-proposal-for-the-responsible-use-of-ai-on-stack-overflow?noredirect=1#comment961978_425211) on its platform. Cf. most academic journals that now allow the responsible use of generative AI, e.g. [PNAS](https://www.pnas.org/post/update/pnas-policy-for-chatgpt-generative-ai). The [quality of ChatGPT4](https://www.semafor.com/article/03/15/2023/how-gpt-4-performed-in-academic-exams) has also been become much better than that of the free tier, ChatGPT3.5, see e.g. here for some recent [maths benchmarks](https://arxiv.org/abs/2306.08997). Most discussion on SO on ChatGPT is highly outdated and concerns mainly ChatGPT3. Of course, as in all guidelines on responsible use of AI, the **use of ChatGPT should then be disclosed** (in line with the **referencing requirements**), which currently is almost impossible, as doing that often results in the answer being deleted. Doing so would also enable other user to scrutinize those answers a little more if need be.

Answer (score -2):

Here is my rules of thumb. Please note that in the end the final choice should come from someone with experience with a bunch of GPT generated content who will recognize this. But these are generally giveaways:

1. Is it factually wrong? This doesn't necessarily making it unchecked AI, but it’s regardless **a bad answer**. Editing the answer should remove this.
2. Does it have a lot that is not useful? Often ChatGPT will give a general introduction to the topic at hand. Editing the answer should remove this.
3. Can the user respond well to comments? Oftentimes if the user does not know what they are writing about, then they will not be able to accurately and usefully respond to any comments. And don't get me started on GPT-generated comments...Those are obvious
4. Does it have some of ChatGPT's favorite starters? GPT loves "Here's an example of how you could use" and similar starters. Editing will generally remove that as it isn't too useful.

Note that these don't necessarily make a post actually unedited GPT or not. The best way to tell is have human who has seen it a lot (like our moderators) make the call.