# When discussing in chat about an alleged CoC violation, is it ok to link to the post containing the alleged CoC violation? If not, how to discuss it?

Tags: discussion, chat, moderation, code-of-conduct

When discussing in the chat about an alleged CoC violation, is it ok to link to the post containing the alleged CoC violation? If not, how to publicly discuss the alleged CoC violation?

Motivation of the chat discussion: discussing if the alleged CoC violation is actually a CoC violation.

Answer (score 11):

It's going to depend. First and foremost I'm not a big fan of such discussions happening in chat at all, to me they always seem better suited to specific site meta as that means whatever outcome there is, it will be available more easily for future reference should that be needed. If you can, make it generic instead of about a specific example too, that way you have something that can be applied to future similar situations, hopefully without rules-lawyering about the situation not being *exactly* the same.

If whatever post this is about wasn't deleted after flagging it, it seems fair game to link to it, to me. Otherwise, there's a reason users with 10K reputation points can see deleted posts, as stated in the [help center](https://meta.stackexchange.com/help/privileges/moderator-tools):

> Make sure what is being deleted should have been deleted, and bring unnecessary or harmful deletions to the attention of the community and/or moderator team.

Just use the 'share' link in such cases, and make sure the unsuspecting user is warned about what they might be seeing. Again, probably best to do this on site-specific meta though, not in chat. Or use the Contact Us option if you [think a moderator abused their privileges](https://meta.stackexchange.com/q/28867/369802) and you suspect a site specific meta post will not have the desired effect.

If we're talking about stuff that's already been deleted being shared through screenshots, copy-pasting, way back machine, Imgur, Reddit, Twitter, Github Gist or whatever else is out there that allows you to make something deleted visible to *everyone* again, just don't do it. It only proliferates the alleged violation and will require more cleanup than necessary if the outcome of the discussion is that it *is* a violation.

Comment: Thanks. "If we're talking about stuff that's already been deleted being shared through screenshots, copy-pasting, way back machine, Imgur, Reddit, Twitter, Github Gist or whatever else is out there that allows you to make something deleted visible to everyone again, just don't do it." that would prevent public discussions.  Does that mean SE makes it impossible to public discuss CoC violations?

Comment: Franck - No, it does not mean SE makes it impossible to publicly discuss CoC violations.

Comment: @RoryAlsop how to publicly discuss the alleged CoC violation?

Comment: If I were you, Franck, I'd follow the process as defined, as it works, rather than subvert it.

Comment: @RoryAlsop Does the process make it possible to publicly discuss the alleged CoC violation? (possible = allowed without getting suspended)

Comment: The process works just fine. What is it about the process that you don't like? The bits that need to be private stay private. The rest can be discussed.

Comment: @RoryAlsop I am trying to understand the process. Does the process make it possible to publicly discuss the alleged CoC violation? (possible = allowed without getting suspended)

Comment: Now I think you are wilfully pretending to be ignorant, in order to try and find loopholes, Franck. Read what people have written. I'm not going to bother trying to discuss yet another of these with you any further.

Comment: @RoryAlsop I'm asking these questions to help me learn Stack Exhange. I don't understand how one can publicly discuss a CoC violation if one can't mention its content or give a link to its publicly accessible version of it's content. In other words, the part of my question "If not, how to publicly discuss the alleged CoC violation?" is unanswered.